# Mocking System.Web.Caching.Cache - Mock or check for null?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, caching, design-patterns, moq

I'm writing some unit test and am wondering whether it's advantageous to mock the `Cache` and if so, how?

Currently in my tests I'm mocking out the `HttpContextBase` and wrapping it in a custom `HttpContextFactory`:

```
var mockedHttpContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

IHttpContextFactory httpContextFactory = new HttpContextFactory 
{ 
     Current = mockedHttpContextBase.Object 
};
```

and when my code consumes an `IHttpContextFactory` I check if the cache is null before doing anything with it.

```
var cache = _httpContextFactory.Current.Cache;

Func<SomeReturnType> doSomeWork = () => _foo.someMethodIExecute(param1,param2);

return cache != null ? cache.GetOrStore("doSomeWorkCacheKey",doSomeWork, 900) 
                     : doSomeWork.Invoke();
```

Is it right to check for the cache being null like this each time I use it or would you mock the cache also in the test so that it's not null when running your unit tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code assumes cache can be `null` and performs checks before accessing it (as it does now), you need to have two unit tests for each *cache access*:

- cache exists and item is stored and retrieved (checking `GetOrStore` call)
- cache is null and you simply assert delegate invocation

If this is common pattern (null checking), instead of having two tests each time cache dependency is required, I suggest wrapping it into [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and have it tested once and later simply use NOP as a dependency that can be mocked.

**Edit**: cache "mocking" example

```
var cache = new Cache();
// Add takes more parameters; fill whatever is necessary to make it work
cache.Add("doSomeWorkCacheKey", doSomeWork, ...);
var mockedHttpContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
// tell your mock to return pre-configured cache
mockedHttpContextBase.Setup(m => m.Cache).Returns(cache);

IHttpContextFactory httpContextFactory = new HttpContextFactory 
{ 
    Current = mockedHttpContextBase.Object 
};
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. With regard to point 1, how would you write a test that depends on the cache existing? How would you mock the cache in this case to perform the test?

Comment: @JamieDixon: you can't really mock `Cache` as it's sealed; you'll have to pre-configure it using real `Cache` implementation and make your `HttpContextBase` mock return that pre-configured cache when requested. I've added example to my post.

Comment: Thanks again Jimmy. I appreciate your time and help. I've added an answer myself after doing more searching. I seems that using `HttpRuntime.Cache` is more appropriate since it'll instantiate everything it needs to work where as `System.Web.Caching.Cache` will throw `NullReferenceExeption`'s if everything isn't configured.

Answer (score 15):

After a bit of searching it seems that I can use `HttpRuntime.Cache` instead of `System.Web.Caching.Cache` when writing my unit tests.

Such that:

```
var mockedHttpContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
mockedHttpContextBase.Setup(m => m.Cache).Returns(HttpRuntime.Cache);
```

The cache should never be `null` (it would be an appropriate exception if it was) so I can remove the null reference checking from my code.

Comment: Good move sidestepping the unMoq'able sealed System.Web.Caching.Cache with HttpRuntime.Cache

Comment: This didn't work for me because my tests are async. Therefore, `HttpRuntime.Cache` shares state, and not per test. It does work when running tests individually.

Comment: To be clear - you don't instantiate a cache in this case.  Just add your items to HttpRuntime.Cache before using the mocked version.

`HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(cacheKey, sampleUser, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.Setup(x => x.Cache).Returns(HttpRuntime.Cache);`

Comment: This didn't work for me either because my tests run in parallel. @BartVerkoeijen, did you figure out a way to mock cache objects per test?

Comment: @ShervinShahrdar I didn't find a way, but as a workaround I selected in Visual Studio's Test Explorer with a toggle to run the tests synchronously, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @BartVerkoeijen Wouldn't that cause a performance issue if you have thousands of tests? My workaround was to clear the cache at the end of every test in [TearDown]. Seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, is to setup your unit test with a real instance of IMemory cache, instead of a mocked one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).